Using TransitionDrawable to crossfade drawables. Can the aspect ratio be preserved?
I'm trying to crossfade between backgrounds in an Android app I'm making. TransitionDrawable seems to be the best way to accomplish this. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this without squashing or stretching the resultant image. Here's a sample of my code:
            val imageResource = setSpecialImage(principalEvent)
            if (isFirstTimeLoadingBackground) {
                isFirstTimeLoadingBackground = false
            } else {
                val metrics: DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
                val screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels
                val screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels
                val bitmap = Picasso.get().load(imageResource)
                    .resize(screenWidth, screenHeight)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .get()
                val newDrawable = BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
                val backgrounds = arrayOf(backgroundimage.drawable, newDrawable)
                val transition = TransitionDrawable(backgrounds)
                backgroundimage.setImageDrawable(transition)
                backgroundimage.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
                transition.startTransition(100)
            }
            backgroundimage.setImageResource(imageResource)

I have tried to use Picasso to load and alter the second image before using TransitionDrawable(), but it seems the transition itself that causes the problem.

"Can the aspect ratio be preserved?" -- the aspect ratio of what? There are 3 things in your question, each with an independent aspect ratio: the first drawable, the second drawable, and the View on which you are calling setImageResource(). "TransitionDrawable seems to be the best way to accomplish this" -- I would leave the background of that View transparent. Have it be on top of a stack, followed by two ImageView widgets (e.g., in a FrameLayout). Then, use standard crossfade techniques.

Two things to note, although I have not validated whether they will fix your problem:

setCrossFadeEnabled needs to be set (Cross fade is disabled by default)
setBounds(Rect) needs to be called for the two drawables in your variable backgrounds (The setBounds(Rect) method must be called to tell the Drawable where it is drawn and how large it should be.)

